# Handling Checkbox in angular js

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-ng-checked

```
 div class ="col-lg-5 stylethistitle"> 
 <input type=" checkbox" ng-model = "checkedStatus">Show Deactivated Account</div>
```

I need to pass $scope.checkedStatus in my json request as false when it is selected and true when it is unselected.

I need that for showing deactivated accounts.

Included my JS Below

JS :

```
  $scope.checkedStatus = true;

$scope.viewAccount = function(){

              var json = {
        "json": {
    "request": {
      "servicetype": "6",
      "functiontype": "6014",
      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession,
           "data": {
        "shortname": $scope.model.selectShortName,
        "groupzname": $scope.model.selectGname,
        "city": $scope.model.selectCity,
        "state": $scope.model.selectState,
        "country": $scope.model.selectCountry,
        "groupzcode": $scope.model.selectGcode,
         "activationstatus": $scope.checkedStatus,
        "details": false,
        "sortbasedon": $scope.groupzname,
        "offset":$scope.pagination
           }

    }
  }
};
                        $scope.sortkey='';
                        $scope.reverse=false;

              UserService.viewListAccount(json).then(function(response) {

                 if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')
                        {
                   $scope.tableData = response.json.response.data;

                        }

            }); 
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a default value for $scope.checkedStatus in the controller. Set it to true or initial value.

Check doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: I did that , the problem is setting them to false when selected is real challenge for me .

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon just take the opposite value when passing it. !($scope.checkedStatus) will do the thing

Answer (score 0):

you need to set  `$scope.checkedStatus` default to false. and then use it in your json like as -

```
"activationstatus":!($scope.checkedStatus)
```

Comment: how to make them false when checked ??

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon !($scope.checkedStatus) will automatically reverse the value of checkedStatus variable. You need not to do anything special

Comment: I understand that . But when unchecked  I can use this, what if I make them checked .how to change the value I am passing in my json request.